# Integration involving roots, and trigonometry

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Question** $$\int_{0}^{2} (1-\cos t) \sqrt{2(1-\cos t)} \, dt$$

Trying to find a solution to this integral problem, substitution method doesn't seem to work, while using the GDC gives a long decimal answer.

Thanks.

Comment: $$\cos(x) = 1 - 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: What's the name of the method that you used, sir?

Comment: It is better to type your question, rather than just providing a link for it.  It would also be good to explain what you mean by GDC.

Comment: Ah, sorry, will learn how to type the question. GDC is a type of calculator that is able to compute definite integral such as that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and for explaining what GDC means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{2} (1-\cos t) \sqrt{2(1-\cos t)} \, dt &=
  \int_{0}^{2} 2\sin^{2} \frac{t}{2} \sqrt{4\sin^{2} \frac{t}{2}} \, dt \\
  &= 4\int_{0}^{2} \sin^{3}
        \frac{t}{2} \, dt
     \, , \quad 0\leq \sin \frac{t}{2} \leq \sin 1 , \; \forall x\in [0,2] \\
  &= 4\int_{0}^{2}
    \left( 1-\cos^{2} \frac{t}{2} \right)\sin \frac{t}{2} \, dt \\
  &= 4\left[
        -2\cos \frac{t}{2}+\frac{2}{3} \cos^{3} \frac{t}{2}
      \right]_{0}^{2} \\
  &= 4\left( \frac{2}{3} \cos^{3} 1-2\cos 1+2-\frac{2}{3} \right) \\
  &= \frac{8}{3} \cos^{3} 1-8\cos 1+\frac{16}{3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{2}\left(1-\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{3/2}dx\stackrel{1-\cos\left(x\right)=u}{=}\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1-\cos\left(2\right)}\frac{u}{\sqrt{2-u}}du
 $$ $$\stackrel{2-u=v}{=}\sqrt{2}\int_{1+\cos\left(2\right)}^{2}\frac{2-v}{\sqrt{v}}dv=\sqrt{2}\left(\int_{1+\cos\left(2\right)}^{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{v}}-\sqrt{v}\,dv\right)$$ can you take it from here?